# Is Pi a good Development/Post-Production Server

Tags: software-development

I am e PHP Developer and I have a Pi at hand, recently I was setting up a Jenkins-CI in a VM with headless raspbian. And then it hit me, What about the Pi. So my questions are:

> 1. Will the Pi handle a Jenkins CI?
> 2. Will it play nice as GIT server (This is dumb question, please ignore it :D)
> 3. Will it be slow as a local post production server, i.e to deploy the application and run it(to copy the sources on the web server/Apache directory)
> 4. What about throwing Gearman in the Mix ?

Everything will be running on a single Pi with headless raspbian within local network. Basically I do not want to have a running VM all the time.

Comment: Have you considered that the Pi does not have much memory for a java based build server. Unless you are careful it wil swap to death. If gitolite is available it will work nicely as a git server.

Comment: Basically with PHP the thing is a little more effortles i think. (Just runing the unit tests, which I think is not like building Java/C or any other application, wrong?) and I do want it just to push local changes and try out the code, if it gets build - back to the IDE otherwise. Will I exhaust it too much

Comment: Jenkins is written in Java.

Comment: my point was that the builds should not be as resource intensive as the would be, if the builds ware for Java/C/Etc. So with the overhead of jenkins the Pi should not get scared. At least that is what i think

Comment: Well, give it a try.  If you have either OpenJDK or Oracle Java installed, it is just running "java -jar jenkins.war".

Comment: *"Will I exhaust it too much"* Electronic devices do not get tired, they just work continuously up to their capacity.  If you've done some/all of this before, then you must have *some* idea of the resources required.  If not, maybe you should try it out on whatever box you want and find out.  Also, it would seem to mostly depend on the scale of what you are developing -- i.e., "Can it run all this software?", sure, probably.  But that is not the same question as "Will it be fast enough in context?".

Comment: With this question I was looking for opinions and suggestions on the setup, as well as info like @Thor mentioned. I am aware that the machines (at least for the moment) do not get tired or anything, it was a figure of speech. Anyways I tried the setup, to be more precise a part of it and have the results, but need to wait until I try everything :)

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov If you have done some experiments, it would be interesting if you created an answer that incorperated the results.

Comment: Will do later on today :), had a 'blackout' last night :D

Comment: If you have multiple questions, ask multiple questions.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Will it run Jenkins?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1598/how-do-i-install-jenkins), [Will the Pi be slow at running PHP?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3688/optimizing-apache-php-and-mysql), [Can I run git?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8658/can-i-install-git-on-raspbian).. So that leaves only the Gearman question. And the Gearman question is far to vague.. What do you mean with "throwing it in the mix".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a dumb question
You could set it up as a private git server http://www.instructables.com/id/GitPi-A-Private-Git-Server-on-Raspberry-Pi/

For others depends on their cpu and ram use and if its going to be slow/lag.
I've run a flask based app and it wasn't much slower than on a normal server but using nginx not apache as per http://elinux.org/RPi_Nginx_Webserver and with uwsgi
raspberrywebserver.com/cgiscripting/setting-up-nginx-and-uwsgi-for-cgi-scripting.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://antonylees.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/running-jenkins-ci-on-raspberry-pi.html) the Raspberry Pi is unable to run Jenkins-Ci

Comment: `java.io.IOException: No space left on device` looks very solvable with a cheap USB disk drive. And the [bug he raised](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14934) has been closed.

Comment: I don't think that's accurate with Pi 3.  There are several articles on the internet to show how to do this.

Comment: This is non-sense. I'm running Jenkins on Rpi/Rpi2 without any problems, but using 32GB SD card with symlinked /var/lib/jenkins to other (non-root) partition which has enough space for jobs

Answer (score 0):

Probably yes you can run it. Can you use it? NO!

I've tried Teamcity (same container as Jenkins) to build Android project.
i7 ~90secs, Pi II ~30 minutes